# How static class can be set as a property?

Tags: c#

There is a requiremnt to save some options with different detial type, so we use a staic class with static propery.

```
public class DynamicVariableSheet
{
    public static class SendBackOptions
    {
        public static byte IsCancellingBrothersNode { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ForwardOptions
    {
        public static string SignForwardCompareType { get; set; }
        public static float SignForwardCompleteOrder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then the DynamicVariableSheet will be an property in another class:

```
public class Runner
{
    public string RunnerName { get; set; }
    public DynamicVariableSheet DynamicVariableSheet { get; set; }
}
```

I can set some value directly using this code:

```
DynamicVariableSheet.SendBackOptions.IsCancellingBrothersNode = 1;
```

But How can I make a property variable to set value into the Runner class like these code.

```
var runner = new Runner();
runner.AppName = "Order";
runner.DynamicVariableSheet.SendBackOptions.IsCancellingBrothersNode = 1;
```

Comment: Property `public DynamicVariableSheet DynamicVariableSheet` expects and instance of `DynamicVariableSheet` class but static class does not have any instances that's why you can not really do this. Can you explain why you landed in to this situation? What exact problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: So do you want it to be static or not? If you make it static you can't use `runner.DynamicVariableSheet...`. If it is not static, you can't set it directly.

Comment: please describe the thought behind your approach, what is the aim of having a `DynamicVariableSheet` as a property in the runner class? do you want an individual value for each `Runner` ? or do you intend to have the same value for all `Runner` objects?

Comment: There are many dynamic options need to be set in runner class. I almost think if I can write fluently is easy to review these options, the style will be: 

runner.DynamicVariableSheet.SendBackOptions.IsCancellingBrothersNode = 1; 
runner.DynamicVariableSheet.FowardOptions.SignForwardCompareType  = "Sequence";

Comment: `DynamicVariableSheet.SendBackOptions.IsCancellingBrothersNode = 1;` this call is misleading. It does not mean that you access the variable `SendBackOptions` in the class `DynamicVariableSheet`. It means that you access an "inner class"! Is there a reason that you chose to implement it as an inner class? I don't see any abvious reasons (up to now) to do so

Comment: Why you need to have static class? If you really have to have static class then you can directly refer that class in `Runner` class without using it as property.

Comment: "are many dynamic options need to be set in runner class" do you want a set of different values for each individual `Runner` object? can they differ between `Runner runner_1` and `Runner runner_2` ? This is a very important question.

Comment: @MongZhu, Yes, there is a set of different values for each individual Runner object.I just thought if there is a nice way to avoid new keyword every time. It's only once set operation to these dynamic options. It just manage these options using group by group, such as SendBackOption and ForwardOption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well because they are static classes you can only access them like so:
DynamicVariableSheet.SendBackOptions.IsCancellingBrothersNode = value;

If you want to access like this:
runner.DynamicVariableSheet.SendBackOptions.IsCancellingBrothersNode = 1;

Turn SendBackOptions and ForwardOptions into non static classes and place them outside of DynamicVariableSheet. Now you can declare them as properties.

I did it for you below:

```
public class DynamicVariableSheet
{
     public SendBackOptions SendBackOptions { get; set; }
     public ForwardOptions ForwardOptions { get; set; }
}

public class SendBackOptions
{
     public byte IsCancellingBrothersNode { get; set; }
}

public class ForwardOptions
{
     public string SignForwardCompareType { get; set; }
     public float SignForwardCompleteOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `DynamicVariableSheet` a static member of the `Runner` class